# What keeps a click event from firing when using .on function?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, click, jquery-on

//HTML:

```
 <table id="requests" class="table table-striped multiselecttable">
        <tbody>
            <tr data-uid="209" style="cursor: pointer; ">
                <td class="span5">Username</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Approve</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> Reject</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

//JQUERY:

```
if($("#requests").length) {
    //individual request approve button
    $("#requests .btn-inverse").click(function(e){
        //works!
        $(this).removeClass("btn-inverse").addClass("btn-danger").html("<i class='icon-white icon-remove'></i> Are you sure?");
    });
    $("#requests .btn-success").click(function(e){
        //works!
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#requests").on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e){
        alert('why u no trigger (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

When I am clicking on the .btn-danger, nothing is happening at all. The other two functions (with clicks) are working.. There is a lot of other javascript; is there a way I can tell if anything is happening when it gets clicked?

Comment: Is it not supposed to be written $("#element").on("click", function() {}); ?

Comment: You can use an optional selector to filter descendants

Comment: $("#requests .btn-danger").on('click', '', function(e){ perhaps? (Sam is right I guess)

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/a4wPk/ (After removing syntax error)

Comment: @Lix: I confused 2 class names. Thought there are 2 different handlers for the same element

Answer (score 1):

Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/JTrKZ/

You are missing closing `});` Also I aint sure about `//if($("#requests").length) {` but you know whats going on I reckon.

Hope it help the cause `:)`

**code**

```
//if($("#requests").length) {
    //individual request approve button
    $(".btn-inverse").click(function(e){
        //works!

        $(this).removeClass("btn-inverse").addClass("btn-danger").html("<i class='icon-white icon-remove'></i> Are you sure?");

    });
    $("#requests .btn-success").click(function(e){
        //works!
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#requests").on('click', '.btn-danger', function(e){
        alert('why u no trigger (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻');
        e.stopPropagation();
    }); // <----- Here this was missing;
//}​
```

Comment: Ok but why does it say `//Works`. The code cannot work at all if there is a syntax error. So either the code worked this whole time or the comment is lying.

Comment: @Esailija Howz it going bruv `:)` Lol I reckon latter is the reality i.e. comment #lying < might be > ; Coz code was working after syntax fix.

Comment: :P I am always wary of answering syntax errors,  in 99% of the cases OP just pasted the code wrong.

Comment: It's working in my code on the actual site.. the syntax error was a result of copying.  (the `//if($("#requests").length) {` thing is to skip past code that won't be necessary on a certain page for same js file over multiple pages)

Comment: Given that works by itself there theoretically must be something else in my code interfering.. ?

Comment: @Damon Yep I reckon `:)` also you had small syntax error with the way brackets were closed for the `.on` hope it helps, or make a jsfiddle will take a look,

Answer (score 0):

.on was added in jQuery version 1.7, so if you are using an older version, it won't work.